# Java comparing Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, primitive

I have two Arrays of unknown type...is there a way to check the elements are the same:

```
public static boolean equals(Object a , Object b) {
  if (a instanceof int[])
    return Arrays.equals((int[]) a, (int[])b);
  if (a instanceof double[]){
    ////etc
}
```

I want to do this without all the instanceof checks....

Comment: Added some method declaration parts (public static ...) - otherwise it looked for me as ruby method call with passed block :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[ArrayUtils.isEquals()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#isEquals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang) does exactly that. It also handles multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Is there any benefit to use non-core library for this? If not it's better to go with standard Arrays.equals instead. I just don't wont to confuse any people looking to the selected answer. It feels more naturally to use standard method than the one from Apache Commons. I choose Arrays.equals instead

Comment: Okay - looks like the issue is that with Arrays.equals and Arrays.deepEquals you can't pass arrays as object like in ArrayUtils.isEquals - got it now.

Comment: `ArrayUtils.isEquals()` is now deprecated in favor of `java.util.Objects.deepEquals()`.

Answer (score 11):

You should try `Arrays.deepEquals(a, b)`

Answer (score 5):

Arrays utilities class could be of help for this:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

There is a method:

```
equals(Object[] a, Object[] a2)
```

That compares arrays of objects.

Answer (score 1):

If the array type is unknown, you cannot simply cast to `Object[]`, and therefore cannot use the methods (`equals`, `deepEquals`) in `java.util.Arrays`.
You can however use reflection to get the length and items of the arrays, and compare them recursively (the items may be arrays themselves).

Here's a **general utility method to compare two objects** (arrays are also supported), which allows one or even both to be null:

```
public static boolean equals (Object a, Object b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return true;
    }
    if (a == null || b == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (a.getClass().isArray() && b.getClass().isArray()) {

        int length = Array.getLength(a);
        if (length > 0 && !a.getClass().getComponentType().equals(b.getClass().getComponentType())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (Array.getLength(b) != length) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (!equals(Array.get(a, i), Array.get(b, i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return a.equals(b);
}
```