# How compare two arrays of objects with assertArrayEquals

Tags: arrays, junit, assert

I want to compare two arrays of objects.

but there is not suitable method found for that method since it doesnt accept objects other from String, Integer etc..

I already override Equals method on the objects of the array.

But how do i pass the array to the method?

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(esperado.getListaEquiposTorneo(), resultado.getListaEquiposTorneo());
```

//esperado.getListaEquiposTorneo(), resultado.getListaEquiposTorneo()) list 1 and 2 of objects made by me

Answer (score 2):

First, you should be able to just use `assertEquals`

```
 Assert.assertEquals(esperado.getListaEquiposTorneo(),
        resultado.getListaEquiposTorneo());
```

I prefer to use `Hamcrest` as it gives better error messages

```
assertThat(actualArray, 
        IsArrayContainingInOrder.arrayContaining(
             expectedArray));

assertThat(resultado.getListaEquiposTorneo(), 
        IsArrayContainingInOrder.arrayContaining(
              esperado.getListaEquiposTorneo()));
```

[IsArrayContainingInOrder](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsArrayContainingInOrder.html)

Answer (score 0):

See Tomasz Nurkiewicz [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869050/java-comparing-arrays):

ArrayUtils.isEquals() from Apache Commons does exactly that. It also handles multi-dimensional arrays.

you can use a simple AssertTrue on the result